# Spotify API help. Response_type=code doesn't work, response_type=token does?

Tags: reactjs, spotify

I am trying to use the Spotify API, and I have been following along with the documentation:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

I can use the Implicit Grants flow, using response_type=token. However, when I try to use Authorization Code flow, using response_type=code, I get errors. My only guess is that I should be running this on my backend, as at the moment it is occuring on my front end, and I was planning on passing the tokens to the back end.

```
connect = () => {
    document.location.href = `${authEndpoint}response_type=token&client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&show_dialog=true`;
  }

const hash = window.location.hash
  .substring(1)
  .split("&")
  .reduce(function (initial, item) {
    if (item) {
      var parts = item.split("=");
      console.log("DECODEEEE",parts)
      initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    }
    return initial;
  }, {});
```

console.log output using response_type=code:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player 401
index.js:72 ===error Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

console.log output using response_type=token:

```
DECODEEEE (2) ["access_token", "REDACTED_ACCESS_TOKEN"]0: "access_token"1: "REDACTED_ACCESS_TOKEN"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
index.js:22 DECODEEEE (2) ["token_type", "Bearer"]
index.js:22 DECODEEEE (2) ["expires_in", "3600"]
```